# CRM 2016 Close Task Error

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

In Dynamics CRM 2016 On premise, whenever I try to close a Task on a specific entity I get an error.
The "close task" is a standard Microsoft button.

The error in the top reads "An error occured. Return to the startpage and try again". Not very usefull. It happens every time.

Debugging have not been helpfull since it does not catch on anywhere.
No Javascript functions are being called on that button and there are no business rules sat up for that page. There are no plugins attached either.

Any ideas what could be causing this error? Or at least how I can dig deeper. I have very little to go on.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Verbose Tracing might help

Comment: Did you update some rollups recently? You can see similar discussions - https://www.crmug.com/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?GroupId=121&MID=7882&tab=digestviewer